# Free Database to Verify the Accreditation of any College or University in the World?

Tags: accreditation

Is there a free, authoritative, trustworthy online database where one can look-up the accreditation of any college or university in the world?

Comment: What type of accreditation are you looking for? Engineering Colleges, Nursing Colleges, Medical colleges all have their own specific accreditations that they maintain -- in addition to the University's own.

Comment: As I think the answer to this question is "NO, but there are many smaller ones", the question doesn't appear to be a good fit for the SE format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For information about **European** institutions, the best starting point for such an online search is possibly the [ENIC-NARIC network](http://www.enic-naric.net/) (European Network of National Information Centres on academic recognition and mobility) which lists the national accreditation organisations.

A list of accredited **Swiss** higher education institutions can be found at the [site of the Rectors' Conference of the Swiss Universities CRUS](http://www.crus.ch/information-programme/recognition-swiss-enic/recognised-or-accredited-swiss-higher-education-institutions.html?L=2).

A database of accredited study programmes in **Germany** can be found at the [site of the German Accreditation Council](http://www.hs-kompass2.de/kompass/xml/akkr/maske.html).

The [Accreditation Organisation of the Netherlands and Flanders NVAO](http://search.nvao.net/home&tab=programme) has a similar database of **Dutch and Flemish** study programmes and institutions.

Answer (score 5):

There is an international database called [UNIVCHECK](http://www.univcheck.org) that allows to validate whether a university is accredited or not. It is both a white list and black list.

Answer (score 4):

In US, US news college rankings will give you this information
http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges

Other databases that you can search are
US Department of Education databases
http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/

http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/search.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links for U.S. colleges and universities, but are there similar databases for worldwide colleges and universities? thanks

Comment: I think each country will / should have their own. Are there any specific countries you are looking at?

Answer (score 1):

The Council for Higher Education Association has a [Database of Institutions and Programs Accredited by Recognized United States Accrediting Organizations](http://www.chea.org/search/default.asp) listing schools accredited by US accrediting agencies, but this also includes schools in other countries that are also accredited by these US organizations.

Answer (score 1):

The [World Higher Education Database](http://whed.net/home.php) contains around 18,500 institutions from 186 countries. It's maintained by the International Association of Universities, a UNESCO-affiliated NGO.